# Connect existing LogicApp to EventGrid subscription

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-eventgrid

I created a new LogicApp with an EventGrid trigger from a StorageAccount. This worked fine. Later I wanted to change the subject filter in the subscription view but got the error

> Invalid event subscription request: Supplied URL is invalid. It cannot be null or empty and should be a proper HTTPS URL like https://www.example.com

So I deleted the subscription and thought that I can create a new one pointing to the existing LogicApp but the drop down list of targets doesn't offer it.

How can I fix the error or point a EventGrid subscription to an existing LogicApp?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why should you get this error when you tried subject filter on the subscription! But in anyway, your existing logic must have used a trigger, if it was a http trigger (When a HTTP request is received) then you could provide the post URL as a webhook in your new EventGrid Subscription. That's how I have my logic app setup and I provide the POST url to EventGridTopic subscriber as a webhook.